# sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: Bateria

Tags: android, sqlite

I get an error every time when i run the application that

> sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: Bateria

### Database code

```
    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String nombre,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, nombre, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table gas(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "estacion text not null, precio intenger not null, fecomgas text not null)");
        db.execSQL("create table aceite(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "marcef text not null, precio intenger not null, fecamac text not null)");
        db.execSQL("create table repuestos(_id integer primary key autoincrement, tipo text not null, precio intenger not null, fecomrep text not null)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnte, int versionNue) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists gas");
        db.execSQL("create table gas(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "estacion text not null, precio intenger not null, fecomgas text not null)");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists aceite");
        db.execSQL("create table aceite(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "marcef text not null, precio intenger not null, fecamac text not null)");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists repuestos");
        db.execSQL("create table repuestos(_id integer primary key autoincrement, tipo text not null, precio intenger not null, fecomrep text not null)");

    }
}
```

The error occurs everytime i call this method

```
public void consulta(View v) {
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "mimoto",
                null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        String tipor = tiporep.getText().toString();
        //String[] repu = new String[] {tipor};
        Cursor filas = bd.rawQuery("select tipo,precio,fecomrep  from repuestos where tipo=" + tipor
                        + "", null);
        if (filas.moveToLast()) {
            tv01.setText(filas.getString(0));
            tv02.setText(filas.getString(1));
            tv03.setText(filas.getString(2));

        } else
            //Toast.makeText(this, "No existe una persona con dicho dni" + tv3,
                //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        bd.close();
        // Fin ultimo tanqueo
    }
```

Bateria is from String tipor, an editext

Comment: Check it out with http://stackoverflow.com/a/12558326/2123594 it may be helpful to you.

Comment: you are tying to get value from column which is not exist in database. so check all query.

Comment: Thanks Swapnil Sonar, i add ' ' to the code `Cursor filas = bd.rawQuery(
    "select tipo,precio,fecomrep  from repuestos where tipo='" + tipor
      + "'", null);` an work

Comment: Have a lookout for your column definitions `precio intenger not null` - you have mispelled `integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is

```
Cursor filas = bd.rawQuery( "select tipo,precio,fecomrep from repuestos where tipo='" + tipor + "'", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because you have enclosed the variable tipor which contains the value bateria in quotes. The query should be

```
select tipo,precio,fecomrep  from repuestos where tipo="' + tipor
                        + "'", null);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the solution is Cursor filas = bd.rawQuery( "select tipo,precio,fecomrep from repuestos where tipo='" + tipor + "'", null);