# Having error on user when login and he is not on database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I got error when i tried to login with a wrong credential, i expected that in gonna receive toast error that wrong credential entered error but it crashes..

i think my database helper stops when it cant find the users email_phone and password. and doesnt send any denying function on my error login activity..

what is the denying fuction or something i am missing

heres my logcat

```
03-09 03:01:09.047 16124-16124/edu.angelo.parentsportal E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: parent
03-09 03:01:09.048 16124-16124/edu.angelo.parentsportal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.angelo.parentsportal, PID: 16124
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: parent (code 1): , while compiling: select * from Parents_Table where (EMAIL_ADDRESS = parent OR PHONE_NUMBER = parent) AND PASSWORD = 123456
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
    at edu.angelo.parentsportal.DatabaseHelper.userExistance(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
    at edu.angelo.parentsportal.Login.userLogin(Login.java:86)
    at edu.angelo.parentsportal.Login.onClick(Login.java:50)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

my DatabaseHelper

```
package edu.angelo.parentsportal;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Parents_Portal.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Parents_Table";
public static final String COL_0 = "ID";
public static final String COL_1 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_2 = "SURNAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "EMAIL_ADDRESS";
public static final String COL_4 = "PHONE_NUMBER";
public static final String COL_5 = "PASSWORD";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, EMAIL_ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE_NUMBER TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String name, String surname, String email_address, String phone_number, String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_2,surname);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,email_address);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,phone_number);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,password);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null , contentValues);
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

public ArrayList<ParentModel> getAllParentsData(){
    ArrayList<ParentModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase mydb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ParentModel parentModel = new ParentModel();
            parentModel.setID(cursor.getString(0));
            parentModel.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            parentModel.setSurname(cursor.getString(2));
            parentModel.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
            parentModel.setPhone_number(cursor.getString(4));
            parentModel.setPassword(cursor.getString(5));
            list.add(parentModel);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}

public void updateData(int id, String name , String surname , String email , String phone_number , String password){
   ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, surname);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, email);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, phone_number);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, password);

    SQLiteDatabase mydb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    mydb.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, COL_0 + "=" + id, null);
    mydb.close();
}

public void deleteParent(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase mydb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    mydb.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_0 + "=" + id, null);
    mydb.close();
}


public ArrayList<ParentModel> getParentLoginData(String emailOrPhone,String password){
    ArrayList<ParentModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+" WHERE ("+COL_3+"= "+emailOrPhone+" OR "+COL_4 +" = "+emailOrPhone+") AND "+COL_5 +" = "+ password;
    SQLiteDatabase mydb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        do {
            ParentModel parentModel = new ParentModel();
            parentModel.setID(cursor.getString(0));
            parentModel.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            parentModel.setSurname(cursor.getString(2));
            parentModel.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
            parentModel.setPhone_number(cursor.getString(4));
            parentModel.setPassword(cursor.getString(5));
            list.add(parentModel);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}

public boolean userExistance(String emailOrPhone, String pwd) {
    String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where (" + COL_3 + " = " + emailOrPhone + " OR " + COL_4 + " = " + emailOrPhone + ") AND " + COL_5 + " = " + pwd;
    SQLiteDatabase mydb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery(sql, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        do {
            ArrayList<ParentModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
            ParentModel parentModel = new ParentModel();
            parentModel.setID(cursor.getString(0));
            parentModel.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            parentModel.setSurname(cursor.getString(2));
            parentModel.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
            parentModel.setPhone_number(cursor.getString(4));
            parentModel.setPassword(cursor.getString(5));
            list.add(parentModel);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
        return true;
    }

    else{
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

My loginActivity

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText editTextEmailPhone;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private Button Login;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
DatabaseHelper mydb;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
ParentModel parentModel;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    editTextEmailPhone = findViewById(R.id.input_username);
    editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_register).setOnClickListener(Login.this);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = mydb.getReadableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_register: {
            userLogin();
            break;
        }

    }


}


private void userLogin() {
    String email = editTextEmailPhone.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        editTextEmailPhone.setError("Email or Phone Number is required");
        editTextEmailPhone.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        editTextPassword.setError("Password is required");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (password.length()<6 ){
        editTextPassword.setError("Minimum of length of password should be 6");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    //if the email&pass is not empty
    else{
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        boolean exists = mydb.userExistance(email, password);
        if(true)
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            SharedPrefs.saveSharedSetting(this, "NoAccount", "false");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Parent_Home.class);

            String parentID;
            String parentName;
            String parentSurname;
            parentID = parentModel.getID();
            parentName = parentModel.getName();
            parentSurname = parentModel.getSurname();

            //Change to prefs
            //intent.putExtra("Ik_CurrentParentID",parentModel.getID());
           // intent.putExtra("Ik_CurrentParentName",parentModel.getName());
           // intent.putExtra("Ik_CurrentParentSurname",parentModel.getSurname());
           // Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome" + parentName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            return;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause is that as **parent** is not enclosed in single quotes, it is considered as an identifier (in this case a column name as you could compare against a column via it's name, hence the message).

## 1. The quick but not so good fix.

It  appears that you have such three instances so you could change :-

```
String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where (" + COL_3 + " = " + emailOrPhone + " OR " + COL_4 + " = " + emailOrPhone + ") AND " + COL_5 + " = " + pwd;
```

to be

```
String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where (" + COL_3 + " = '" + emailOrPhone + "' OR " + COL_4 + " = '" + emailOrPhone + "') AND " + COL_5 + " = '" + pwd + "'";
```

## 2. A better fix, but still some potential issues (see next fix)

However, should the values to compare against be via user input. This leaves the App open to SQL Injection (entering damaging commands via input), as such it is suggested that you utilise the 2nd parameter of rawQuewry method to pass a String array of values that will on a one per basis replace ?'s in the query.

As such it would be considered a safer practice to use :-

```
String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where (" + COL_3 + " = ? OR " + COL_4 + " =?) AND " + COL_5 + " =? ";
String[] args = new String[]{emailOrPhone,emailOrPhone,pwd};
SQLiteDatabase mydb = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery(sql,args);
```

## 3. The better fix.

However, there are convenience methods such as **query** (yuo used the update convenience method), that are considered better than using rawQuery where possible.

The convenience methods build the underlying SQL. As such the recommended way would be to use :-

```
public boolean userExistance(String emailOrPhone, String pwd) {

    SQLiteDatabase mydb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = "(" + COL_3 + "=? OR " + COL_4 + "=?) AND " + COL_5 + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{emailOrPhone,emailOrPhone,pwd}    
    Cursor cursor = mydb.query(TABLE_NAME,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    boolean rv = cusror.getCount() > 0;
    cursor.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- Note that this has also been altered to do away with needless and potentially dangerous code.
- The Cursor is closed, if too many Cursors are left open the App will crash, so it is bad practice to not close Cursors when done with them.
- There is no need to loop through the cursor and extract the data, as all you want to know if any rows have been returned. So the count is used to set the return value to true or false, the cursor is closed and the boolean returned.
- You may wish to have a look at [SQLiteDatabase - query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

***Note the above is in-principle code, it has not been tested or run and may therefore contain some errors.***

***You should also note that you will have a similar issue with getParentLoginData as the SELECT clause is very much the same***.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add one (') before and after `emailOrPhone` because it's a character type. and the query would be like:

```
String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where (" + COL_3 + " = '" + emailOrPhone + "' OR " + COL_4 + " = '" + emailOrPhone + "') AND " + COL_5 + " = " + pwd;
```

for more information you can check this problem: [sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column:kitchen1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558270/sqlite-returned-error-code-1-msg-no-such-columnkitchen1)